# Google mobile vision OCR using webcam(or USB camera) in Android

Tags: android, camera, ocr, webcam

I am currently using Google mobile vision in my Android application to detect text from image or camera frames which is working pretty well.
I am also able to show webcam output in application using [UVCCamera library](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera)

**Problem:**

I want to use external USB camera (webcam) instead of internal hardware camera of Android but am not able to find solution for this. There is no provision to use external camera in mobile vision. I didn't find any documentation for the same.

Is is possible to do this?

Comment: Did you able to get web cam  out put in mobile app?

Comment: yes, using UVCCamera library.

Comment: any updates? Did you solve your problem? I know that, UVCCamera lib using TextureView, however Google mobile vision is using SurfaceView.

Comment: @JavadKhan The problem is not solved. I forced to use android phone internal camera only.

Comment: I'd like to suggest one idea. Now i did it with this way. There's onCaptureResult method in UVCCamera lib. Just get that result file, convert to bitmap and do OCR with TessBaseApi from official lib.

Comment: Yes. Your idea will work for images but you cannot do runtime OCR frame by frame(while camera is open). Please add your idea as answer with some code so that it can help someone.